# m12-073 update causes IIS service unavailable

Tags: windows, iis

I am a developer. I have created a web site and service with Visual Studio 2010. I am running a fully patched Windows 7 computer.

I need to be able to debug it with devices other than my dev computer hitting the web server. I installed IIS 7.5 and configured everything to be working. I was able to debug when another device hit the web site on this dev computer.

That was yesterday. This morning I started up my computer and there was an update from Microsoft. m12-073. It mentioned IIS.

When I started working on this project today after doing the update now I get a service unavailable (503) error on any computer or device NOT the dev computer. The dev computer still works fine.

The only change from yesterday and today is the update and rebooting.

I tried uninstalling the update and that didn't fix it. I tried a system restore to before the update and that didn't work.

I am now stumped. It worked yesterday and doesn't work today with only the update being the change.

Help?

Comment: Did you check, if your AppPool is running?

Comment: Yup. First thing I checked.

Comment: Which computer runs the IIS? Is that your dev-computer? It's kind of odd, that one works and others not - very odd.